# How to accept a JavaScript alert popup in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I have a script which uses Puppeteer to automatically log in to a corporate portal. The login uses SAML. So, when puppeteer opens up an instance of chromium and visits the page, a popup appears on screen to confirm the identity of the user. All I need to do is either manually click on "OK" button or press Enter from keyboard.

I have tried to simulate the pressing of the Enter key using puppeteer but it does not work.

The login screen -

[image: Login screen]

Script -

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


async function startDb() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        defaultViewport:null
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://example.com");
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    console.log('Opened')
};


startDb();
```

**EDIT **

[image: Certificate export]

Comment: Please share the actual site so others can test their code on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1319#issuecomment-371503788):

> Basically just intercept the request, then fire the request off yourself using your favorite httpclient lib, and repond to the intercepted request with the response info.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    // Enable Request Interception
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    // Client cert files
    const cert = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.crt.pem');
    const key = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.key.pem');

    page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
        // Intercept Request, pull out request options, add in client cert
        const options = {
            uri: interceptedRequest.url(),
            method: interceptedRequest.method(),
            headers: interceptedRequest.headers(),
            body: interceptedRequest.postData(),
            cert: cert,
            key: key
        };

        // Fire off the request manually (example is using using 'request' lib)
        request(options, function(err, resp, body) {
            // Abort interceptedRequest on error
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Unable to call ${options.uri}`, err);
                return interceptedRequest.abort('connectionrefused');
            }

            // Return retrieved response to interceptedRequest
            interceptedRequest.respond({
                status: resp.statusCode,
                contentType: resp.headers['content-type'],
                headers: resp.headers,
                body: body
            });
        });

    });

    await page.goto('https://client.badssl.com/');
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: How do we get the cert and key ? I tried to export the certificate from the browser. But I could not find the .pem type export file option. Check EDIT

Comment: Please see if this answer and comment can help: https://superuser.com/a/1292098/333511

Answer (score 0):

Before `page.goto()`, put this code:

```
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
  await dialog.accept();
});
```